# HTML CSS Flask Bootstrap Can't Align DIV?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

why can't I align this div with bootstrap and flask?

```
{% extends "_base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<h1 class="text-center">Welcome {{current_user.email}}!</h1>
<div class="input-group mb-3-center">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Options</label>
    </div>
    <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
      <option selected>Choose...</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I've also tried text-center which works, but only for the Options text.

Thank you be easy, i'm new to bootstrap. Typically I'd just use the  html tags, but that of course doesn't work.

My base.html that has the bootstrap css inside of it fore reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Flask User Management</title>
    <!-- meta -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <!-- styles -->
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename="styles.css")}}">
    {% block css %}{% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>

    {% include "navigation.html" %}

    <div class="container">

      <br>

      <!-- messages -->
      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
      {% if messages %}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {% for category, message in messages %}
          <div class="alert alert-{{ category }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
           {{message}}
           <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}

      <!-- child template -->
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}

    </div>

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    {% block js %}{% endblock %}

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please add the lines of code you used to include Bootstrap in this code? Thanks.

Comment: @KirillMcQuillin Sure, I just did it. Thank you for your reply

Comment: So you want the drop down and it's label to be centered?

Comment: @KirillMcQuillin Yes, I'll put it into a post form and add a submit button later on too. I neglected to mention that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

To center the drop down and it's corresponding label:

```html
{% extends "_base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<h1 class="text-center">Welcome {{current_user.email}}!</h1>
<div class="input-group mb-3-center" style="display: flex;justify-content: center;">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Options</label>
    </div>
    <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
      <option selected>Choose...</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Utilizing [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox), I added `style="display: flex;justify-content: center;"` to the outermost div. View [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-can-i-horizontally-center-an-element) for more options on centering an element horizontally in another element.

**Solution 2**

The first solution will center the drop down and label, but the label will be on the side of the drop down, not the top. This is a solution for centering the 2 elements, while also placing the label on the top of the drop down.

```html
{% extends "_base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<h1 class="text-center">Welcome {{current_user.email}}!</h1>
<div class="input-group mb-3-center" style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;align-items: center;">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Options</label>
    </div>
    <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
      <option selected>Choose...</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see, I still use `flexbox` but now I am setting the `flex-direction` to column, and aligning items to the center.